# React Native & RTK Query - IsLoading on refetch method

Tags: react-native, redux, rtk-query

Why when I use `refetch` method in the code below the `isLoading` value does not return on `true` during the fetch ?

```js
const [matchFilterSelected, setMatchFilterSelected] = useState('explorer')

// Query declaration
const {
  data: matches,
  refetch,
  error: matchesError,
  isLoading: matchesIsLoading,
} = useFetchMatchesQuery(matchFilterSelected)

// Callback function from onPress event
const filterSelectedChanged = (matchesType) => {
  if (matchesType && matchesType !== matchFilterSelected) {
    setMatchFilterSelected(matchesType)
    refetch()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `isLoading` is only true on initial load. You probably want to use `isFetching` - that shows actual activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, all works fine :)